# Paypal - IPN integration with subcription using PHP class

Tags: php, paypal, subscription, paypal-ipn

I'm using a Paypal class available here:
http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html
by Micah Carrick for paypal integration along with IPN.

Now, I want users to subscribe and I want to handle the subscription/unsubscription IPN's.
This is the current code:

```
case 'ipn': 

if ($p->validate_ipn()) {

     // Payment has been recieved and IPN is verified.  This is where you
     // update your database to activate or process the order, or setup
     // the database with the user's order details, email an administrator,
     // etc.  You can access a slew of information via the ipn_data() array.
```

How would I detect if the event is "subscription", "un-subscription" or anything else?

Thanks in advance,
happyhardik

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the type of transaction through the `txn_type` parameter available in the request. Refer to the PayPal manual for [the various types](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id08CTB0S055Z).

`subscr_signup` and `subscr_cancel` indicate subscription and unsubscription appropriately.